# "No such file or directory" using cut in a while read loop in bash

Tags: linux, bash, loops

I have this sample text file text.txt that is in the form

```
fruits    vegetables
apples    cucumbers
oranges    squash
```

and it is tab delimited.

I would like to loop through the file line by line, and extract each column value.

Below is the code the code I have tried.

```
while read p
do
  echo "Line"
  fruit="$(cut -f 1 $p)"

  echo "${fruit}"
done <test.txt
```

My expected output should be something like:

```
Line
fruits
Line
apples
Line
oranges
```

Instead I get this output:

```
Line
cut: fruits: No such file or directory
cut: vegetables: No such file or directory

Line
cut: apples: No such file or directory
cut: cucumbers: No such file or directory

Line
cut: oranges: No such file or directory
cut: squash: No such file or directory
```

Comment: `while IFS=$'\t' read -r col1 rest; do echo "$col1"; done`. There's no reason to use `cut` or anything like it.

Comment: ...that said, in general, you should show your *actual* output, not just expected output.

Comment: ...to explain your immediate bug: `cut -f 1 $p` expects `$p` to expand to a *filename*, which is what `cut` then tries to read from.

Comment: See above running successfully @ https://ideone.com/XMEpTP; I'm going to be closing this question with a duplicate momentarily.

Comment: I just added also the actual output. How would I modify your script to print the second filed as well?

Comment: ("first field" is just a special case of "nth field")

Comment: `read -r col1 col2 rest` puts the first field into `col1`, the second into `col2`, etc.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. I appreciate the help

Comment: See [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for a general discussion of the technique.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to loop through the file line by line, and extract each
>   column value

Is awk not suitable ?

```
awk '{ print "Line"; print $1 }' < test.txt
```